# NameError: name 'image_path' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've read stackoverflow questions and solution seemed to be insert full path however after doing that it gives me name error. I am using windows 10 python 3.7.1

this is my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz


export_graphviz(
        tree_clf,
        out_file = image_path("C:/Users/my_name/Desktop/iris_tree.dot"),# path where you want it to output
        feature_names=iris.feature_names[2:],
        class_names = iris.target_names,
        rounded=True,
        filled=True
)
```

Comment: Where are you importing `image_path`?

Comment: is it not imported when I import export_graphviz?

Comment: Doesn't look like it from your import statement or you are not namespacing it. What makes you think that it would be magically imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly is `image_path`? `export_graphviz` accepts a parameter called `out_file`, which can be a string or a file object:

> file object or string, optional (default=None)

So I would write:

```py
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

f = open("C:/Users/my_name/Desktop/iris_tree.dot", 'w')
export_graphviz(
        tree_clf,
        out_file=f,  # path where you want it to output
        feature_names=iris.feature_names[2:],
        class_names = iris.target_names,
        rounded=True,
        filled=True
)
```

In case you are following "Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow" book by Aurelien Geron, here's the definition of `image_path` from his [GitHub](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/5bb8d2e071852f3b5907679668705e59c0fb4a16/06_decision_trees.ipynb) (Still not doing what you wanted, I would just use my first solution):

```py
import os

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "decision_trees"

def image_path(fig_id):
    return os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID, fig_id)
```

Comment: from my understanding image_path creates a graph using string values. If you output it w/o image_path it will output MS word file where you would have to manually convert it by visiting webgraphviz on browser and copy, paste to create graph.

Comment: `image_path` does not exist. Not in your module and not in `sklearn`. And you can not change the way `export_graphviz` outputs into a file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. Based on [AdamGold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695377/adamgold) and [Jack Stevens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657576/jack-stevens), this is what I did and I converted the dot file to a png (you also can convert it to a pdf).

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

with open("/Users/Desktop/tree.dot", 'w') as f:
export_graphviz(tree_clf, 
                out_file = f,
                feature_names = iris.feature_names[2:],
                class_names = iris.target_names,
                rounded = True, filled = True)

# convert a dot file to a png/pdf
from graphviz import Source

dot_path = "/Users/Desktop/tree.dot"
output = Source.from_file(dot_path, format = "png") # can change png to pdf
output.view()
```